# Angular interceptor - get message from 500 error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-config, interceptor

I'm using an Angular Interceptor and I want to get the **message** from 500 errors (internal server error).

The problem is, that I'm getting the whole HTML in the **rejection.data** in **responseError** inside Interceptor (screenshot below).

I read that I have to configure **web.config** but I'm still getting the whole HTML. I just want to get the message.

Is it possible to do that?

Angular Interceptor:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q, $rootScope) {

        return {
            request: function (config) {

                //the same config / modified config / a new config needs to be returned.
                return config;
            },
            requestError: function (rejection) {

                //Initializing error list
                if ($rootScope.errorList == undefined) {
                    $rootScope.errorList = [];
                }

                $rootScope.errorList.push(rejection.data);

                //It has to return the rejection, simple reject call doesn't work
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            },
            response: function (response) {

                //the same response/modified/or a new one need to be returned.
                return response;
            },
            responseError: function (rejection) {

                //Initializing the error list
                if ($rootScope.errorList == undefined) {
                    $rootScope.errorList = [];
                }

                //Adding to error list
                $rootScope.errorList.push(rejection.data);

                //It has to return the rejection, simple reject call doesn't work
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    });
}]);
```

Web.Config

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" errorMode="Detailed"></httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

[image]

Edit:
I want to get the Message from the exception snapshot

[image: Image2]

Comment: what are you getting in data.message?

Comment: Nothing. Because in data I have whole HTML like in 1st image. I made an edit - take a look.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to get the message from 500 errors (internal server error).

Use `response.statusText` to get the message:

```
responseError: function (errorResponse) {

    //Initializing the error list
    if ($rootScope.errorList == undefined) {
        $rootScope.errorList = [];
    }

    //Adding to error list
    $rootScope.errorList.push(errorResponse.statusText);

    //It has to return the rejection, simple reject call doesn't work
    return $q.reject(errorResponse);
}
```

From the Docs:

> The response object has these properties:
>
> - data – `{string|Object}` – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
> - status – `{number}` – HTTP status code of the response.
> - headers – `{function([headerName])}` – Header getter function.
> - config – `{Object}` – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
> - statusText – `{string}` – HTTP status text of the response.

-- [AngularJS $http Service API Reference -- General Usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage)